# zsh _arguments completion that gradually reveals options

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I have at the moment a completion function that looks something like this (except way more entries)

```bsh
_arguments \
  '-check[do a check]' \
  '-play[play a specific song]:songnumber' \
  '-test.n=[run test specified number of times]:n' \
  '-test.dir=[run test in a specific working dir]:dir: _path_files -/' \
  '-test.v[run tests verbose]' \
  '-log[delete all log files]' \
  '*:inputfiles: _files'
```

upon tabbing this leads to printout like that:

```
pseyfert@robusta:~ > program -⇥
option:
-check     -- do a check
-log       -- delete all log files
-play      -- play a specific song
-test.dir  -- run test in a specific working dir
-test.n    -- run test specified number of times
-test.v    -- run tests verbose
```

One pattern is that a considerable number of options starts with `-test.` and I am often not interested in them, so when looking for an option that I don't know by heart, the entire `-test.` block is somewhat spam. I'd prefer to group the options to a printout like that:

```
pseyfert@robusta:~ > program -⇥
option:
-check     -- do a check
-log       -- delete all log files
-play      -- play a specific song
-test.     -- test options
```

and then when reaching `-test.` reveal what's behind:

```
pseyfert@robusta:~ > program -test.⇥
option:
-test.dir  -- run test in a specific working dir
-test.n    -- run test specified number of times
-test.v    -- run tests verbose
```

I realized I can get in the right direction with a minus after the option

```bsh
_arguments \
  '-check[do a check]' \
  '-play[play a specific song]:songnumber' \
  '-log[delete all log files]' \
  '-test.-[test options]:testopts: _testopts' \
  '*:inputfiles: _files'
```

such that no space gets added after `-test.` and a space will not be interpreted as "option continues". What I lack in my repertoire is the `_testopts` function. I'm tempted to use `_arguments` again, but that requires leading `-` after the `-test.`. With `_values` I am not aware of a method to place the descriptions and don't know how to continue into other functions like `_path_files -/` above.

Are there any examples for gradual option revealing or hints how to best change the design of my completion?